# Rails - Update parent relation on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two `has_many` relationships present on 3 models.
Client has_many Projects
Project has_many Tasks
Client has_many Tasks through Projects

What I'm trying to do is find the 'nearest' start date, and 'nearest end date' of the tasks a client has applicable.

I have something similarly working to update the `Project` when an earlier/later `Task` is saved, but I seem to be having issues with updating the `Client`.

The purpose of this is simpler querying for datatables, since I couldn't get filters to work on `Client.project.tasks.start_date`

```
def update_project_record
    client = Client.find(project.client_id)
    project.start_date = self.task_start_date if self.task_start_date < project.start_date 
    project.end_date = self.task_end_date if self.task_end_date > project.end_date
    if client.nearest_project_start.present?
        client.nearest_project_start = self.task_start_date if self.task_start_date < client.nearest_project_start
    else
        client.nearest_project_start = self.task_start_date
    end
    if client.furthest_project_end.present?
        client.furthest_project_end = self.task_end_date if self.task_end_date > client.furthest_project_end
    else
        client.furthest_project_end = self.task_end_date
    end
end
```

The `project.start_date` and `end.date` section work - I have made a field within client itself to house the 'earliest' and 'latest' task dates, but it currently is always printing out Nil.

I used the `if/else` wrapper because I was getting a 
`ArgumentError: comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with nil failed`
response without it.

What's weird is if I byebug before that function ends, `client`, `project`, and `task` are all showing their proper data, AND Client is showing the date it should. But if I use Rails Console, or the app itself, to save the record, Client is never getting updated.

This seems like a simple issue but I'm unsure how to figure out at which step it's having issues updating. I've tried using Console to perform the same query manually and sure enough it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `client.save` at the end of your method.

Comment: Sure enough, that made the app work. Is there any specific reason why I didn't need to call Project.save for it's portion to work?

Comment: Can't be sure without seeing the code. But I assume you used some variation of `#update` if you didn't call `#save`, or the method is called in a `#before_save` callback.